# Academia vs. Industry for Machine Learning

Tags: computer-science, academic-life, industry, machine-learning

For PhD students in machine learning, academia vs. industry is an increasingly strange choice. Getting a faculty job at a good university is still quite hard, but the pay is hugely lower than in industry (~ 120k for an assistant professor job at a top 10 school, vs. ~ 500k for a research scientist position at Google/FB/Amazon for a similar candidate).

What is the allure of academia? It comes with grant pressure, teaching huge classes, and huge opportunity cost in salary.

Comment: Salary isn't everything. Different people choose different jobs.

Comment: I'm always surprised that so many people simply *assume* that salary is the main (or only) criterion and trumps everything else. It seems pretty obvious that that isn't true (e.g., why doesn't everyone become ML researcher then? why do people study certain disciplines in the humanities? etc.).

Comment: I question 500K$ for a starting salary.

Comment: no one's talking about starting salary ;-) Also, that would be an unfair comparison since becoming an assistant professor at a top university likely includes a few years of postdoc. It still sounds quite high, even after some time, but plausible.

Comment: For entry level I doubt the 500/120 ratio. Each comes with different kinds of pressures, expectations, and longevity. And you'd be mistaken to imagine the competition for a position you might hold at Google, FaceBook, etc., isn't fierce year after year.

Comment: Tenure is a big draw - note that nobody has worked an entire career at Google yet. Teaching can be very rewarding. And don't forget that the professor's salary is a 9-month salary and they can consult (both in the summers and otherwise) which can substantially increase their income if they are in something like ML.

Comment: @user2316602: One side of the comparison, the 120k side, indicated "assistant professor" so it's easy to infer the OP intended a beginning-of-career comparison.

Comment: Salary isn't everything, but the main draw --- actually doing ML research --- seems similar in both academia and industry. If anything industry provides more resources. My question is what is the draw of academia? Is it really just the joy of teaching?

Comment: Re: 500k in industry --- this is the definitely the upper end of the spectrum, but we're talking about people who would be getting top faculty jobs, so also the very top end.

Comment: @JonCuster good point about 9 month salary; so maybe the better academic comparison would be 160k taking into account 3 months of summer pay.

Comment: @MLStudent - some professors I know make more in consulting than from their university salary. Or their start up companies. Lots of freedom in the university job, much less in an industry job.

Comment: why becoming a research scientist at Google, when you can become a quant?

Comment: "the main draw --- actually doing ML research --- seems similar in both academia and industry" - besides a few rare positions that are more academic-like roles funded by a big company like Google (which are as competitive as any, it's not like you can pencil yourself in as getting this job because you have a degree), it is definitely **not** true that the draw of doing research is the same in academia and industry.

Answer (score 1):

Other engineering disciplines can have a vaguely similar pay gap, especially when comparing with a top industry job as you describe (and doubly so when comparing living in SF to a college town)

A common argument is for the freedom offered in an academic job. Another is that industry jobs are often more boring. I think there is also something to be said for being able to potentially "leave your mark" in academia in a way that isn't necessarily possible working an industry job. Lastly, I'll point out that some cultures think very highly of professors, in the same way US culture tends to think most highly of doctors.

Comment: Does that imply that the US culture doesn't think highly of professors (as opposed to doctors)?

Comment: No. Just that doctor is pretty much the undisputed most prestigous job, according to popular opinion. If you do some quick searches, you'll find various surveys that back this up. Scientist also ranks highly though. (Do people consider a professor to be a scientist? It's not entirely clear from the surveys)